# Как парсить HTML и доставать content из <meta>?

Tags: php, html, парсер, simple-html-dom

Могу ли я парсить HTML и доставать из `<meta>` допустим вот такое:

```
content="https://cdn1.kinogo.by/movies/eca77723afbce23d62598fe607a507f3c35c8e21/ec233074d5f12bb8e59fff0aff0960b5:2018050310/360.mp4"
```

При этом еще и фильтровать это, чтобы, например в конце строки было `.mp4` или `.ogg`?

Comment: @entithat, Можно пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm и Под заголовком *How to find HTML elements?* написано как можно найти нужный тэг с нужным атрибутом.

Comment: @entithat, спасибо, я это уже читал, но мне надо чтобы оно доставало content и в этой строке был в конце .mp4 или .ogg

Comment: Тогда, например берём `$ret = $html->find('[content]');`, и потом с помощью `preg_match()` и регулярки проверяем на наличие `.mp4|.ogg`, если совпадений не найдено, то там уже Вам решать что дальше..

Comment: @entithat, Сорри, но не могли бы вы кинути полный код, знаю, задолбал, может в ответ, буду рад отметить правильным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так. В цикле можете делать то, что Вам нужно.

```
// Подключили библиотеку
require('simple_html_dom.php'); 

// Создали DOM с файла либо по УРЛ
$html = file_get_html('URL or FILE');

// Нашли все мета-теги
foreach($html->find('meta[content]') as $element) {

    // Если нашли совпадение в конце .mp4 либо .ogg, то выводим. 
    if (preg_match('~(.mp4|.ogg)$~', $element->content)) {
        echo $element->content; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Обращайтесь :))

Comment: Слушайте, а вы не знаете как сделать так же, только для youtube?

Comment: В каком смысле для youtube?

Comment: Ну, вот я попробовал запустить с той ссылкой - все найс, но когда с ютубом - пустота (или так нельзя?)

Comment: @DanyloKiz ну возможно в заголовках Ютуба нету такий тегов.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Возможно я уже вас достал. Но, можно задать вам один вопрос не по теме? Я видел, что вы хорошо в PHP знаетесь. Вопрос: Может ли быть такое, что php сам сохраняет значение в переменной?

Comment: я допустим ввел значение в input field потом отправляю значение через session в следующий php файл и там оно выводиться, но когда запускаю так же только второй раз - показывается первое значение.

Comment: куда вам можно кинуть?

Comment: Вот, откуда все начинается - https://jsfiddle.net/danylokiz/aqrrsasf/, продолжение - https://jsfiddle.net/danylokiz/dgvzry3n/, обработка - https://jsfiddle.net/danylokiz/4to2r6av/

Comment: Все регистрация, логин, session_start();

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду "Попробуйте отдебажить код", чесно я просто новенький в php, я больше в swift

Comment: Как вы сказали запустил "exit($_SESSION['url']);" - результат тот самый - показывается самое первое значение и только

Comment: @DanyloKiz, тут явно проблема во втором файле..

Comment: Может в третьем?

Comment: @DanyloKiz нет, в третьем Вы просто присваиваете значение, там просто негде сделать ошибку. А вот во вторым..